# Is it possible to capture audio stream in browser via flash/js/silverlight?

Tags: flash, browser, audio

Im working on a project where we need to capture a 5 sec clip of whatever is being played through the users line-out (audio).

Is it possible to do this reliably through a browser (using flash/silvelight/js..) ?

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of the Flash Player coming out, version 10.1 and AIR 2.0 will support the ability to get (and record) the raw data coming in through the microphone.

You can find tutorials and information about this at http://www.getmicrophone.com/

You'll also notice on that site Microsoft has also announced this feature for Silverlight 4.

Comment: Im actually looking to capture a small clip of whats being played through the users speakers/line out (i.e internet radio, music..etc). 

Do you know if this is possible in flash ?